# Sum Node values using LINQ to XML

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

Sample XML:

```
<PTC_FareBreakdowns>
  <PTC_FareBreakdown>
    <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
    <FareBasisCodes>
      <FareBasisCode>RGOSAVE</FareBasisCode>
    </FareBasisCodes>
    <PassengerFare>
      <BaseFare Amount="4400" CurrencyCode="INR" />
      <Taxes>
        <Tax Amount="233" CurrencyCode="INR" TaxCode="OC" TaxGroupCode="SF" TaxGroupName="Taxes &amp;amp; Fees" />
        <Tax Amount="218" CurrencyCode="INR" TaxCode="OC" TaxGroupCode="SF" TaxGroupName="Taxes &amp;amp; Fees" />
        <Tax Amount="3500" CurrencyCode="INR" TaxCode="YQ" TaxGroupCode="SF" TaxGroupName="Taxes &amp;amp; Fees" />
        <Tax Amount="440" CurrencyCode="INR" TaxCode="OC" TaxGroupCode="SF" TaxGroupName="Taxes &amp;amp; Fees" />
        <Tax Amount="173" CurrencyCode="INR" TaxCode="OC" TaxGroupCode="SF" TaxGroupName="Taxes &amp;amp; Fees" />
        <Tax Amount="0" TaxCode="B2BMarkup" />
      </Taxes>
      <TotalFare Amount="8964" CurrencyCode="INR" />
      <Markups>
        <Markup Amount="0.0000" CurrencyCode="INR" Description="0.0  for client - 26472" MarkupCode="DisplayMarkup" Type="M" />
        <Markup Amount="0" CurrencyCode="INR" Description="0.0 % on base fare  for client - " MarkupCode="DisplayMarkup" MarkupType="M" Type="M" />
        <Markup Amount="0" Description="0.0% on fule surcharge  3500.0for client" MarkupCode="DisplayMarkup" MarkupType="M" Type="M" />
      </Markups>
    </PassengerFare>
  </PTC_FareBreakdown>
</PTC_FareBreakdowns>
```

The LINQ, I have tried so far,

```
  var Adult = from Main in xd.Descendants(ns + "PTC_FareBreakdown")
              from Sub1 in Main.Elements(ns + "PassengerTypeQuantity")
              where Sub1.Attribute("Code").Value == "ADT"
              from Sub2 in Main.Elements(ns + "PassengerFare").Elements(ns + "Taxes").Elements(ns + "Tax")
              where Sub2.Attribute("TaxCode").Value == "OC"
              select new
              {
                  OC = Sub2.Attributes("Amount").Sum(nd => Int32.Parse(nd.Value)),
              };
```

It returns the value as 233,218,440 and 173. **But It must return the sum of all value [233+218+440+173=1064].**

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var query = xd.Descendants(ns + "PTC_FareBreakdown")
               .Elements(ns + "PassengerFare")
               .Elements(ns + "Taxes")
               .Elements(ns + "Tax")
               .Where(tax => (string)tax.Attribute("TaxCode") == "OC") 
               .Sum(tax => (int)tax.Attribute("Amount"));
```

Result: `1064`

Comment: Thanks. But it returns' 0 'as value,instead of 1064.

Comment: @Thiri try to remove `ns` specification from attribute selection (I didn't have your namespace, thus verified without namespace)

Comment: can i have the same result on above format like what i tried ?

Comment: @Thiri yes, do `select (int)Sub2.Attribute("Amount")`, and then wrap all your query into Sum: `var Adult = (..query..).Sum();`

Answer (score 1):

@lazyberenzovsky's answer using LINQ keyword syntax:

```
var Adult = (
    from tax in xd.Descendants("PTC_FareBreakdown")
                   .Elements("PassengerFare")
                   .Elements("Taxes")
                   .Elements("Tax")
    where (string)tax.Attribute("TaxCode") == "OC"
    select (int)tax.Attribute("Amount")
).Sum();
```

Of course, you could probably just use:

```
var Adult = (
    from tax in xd.Descendants("Tax")
    where (string)tax.Attribute("TaxCode") == "OC"
    select (int)tax.Attribute("Amount")
).Sum();
```

if this is the only place you have a `Tax` element in your XML.